# Greater Than / Equal To: using specific words

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula with an outcome of Pass or Fail based upon two criteria:

Column A relates to a document's required approval level, ranging between Blue, Green, Yellow, Red, Purple, and Black (Blue being the lowest approval level and Black being the highest)

Column B relates to the level of the agent who approved the document (same color ranking)

The Pass/Fail formula will be housed in Column C and will check any given agent level in Column B against the corresponding document level in Column A (e.g. Agent level-Green in B4 against Document level-Blue in A4)

With the above in mind: Is there any way to assign a ranking order for the aforementioned levels from lowest to highest using a formula? I suppose I would need two separate formulas: one to account for the ranking an the other to measure Column B against Column A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your list in order in a range and use MATCH to return a relative location:

```
=IF(MATCH(B2,G:G,0)>=MATCH(A2,G:G,0),"PASS","FAIL")
```

[image]

---

If you want to "hard code" the values and skip the helper column just put `{"Blue","Green","Yellow","Red","Purple","Black"} in place of`G:G` in the formula.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I appreciate the assistance!